# Install Express in Ubuntu and new node.js project in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

1. I have installed the node.js including npm.
2. I try to install Express:

   1. `npm install -g express-generator`  **failed**

      [image: always waiting...., I think it is not the network problem]
   2. `sudo apt install node-express-generator`  **succeeded**

      `express -V`  **4.0.0**
3. I try to create the node.js project in WebStorm, but can't get the express-generator version. My WebStorm version is 2017.1.3

   [image]

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html

Comment: I have solved the problem, because I used the proxy, and have not configured the npm proxy, so that npm install -g express-generator failed, then webstorm can get the express-generator version correctly. But when I installed the express-generator by **sudo apt install node-express-generator**, but webstorm can't get it. Whether because I have not install it by global, or have not installed it by npm?

Comment: you solved this?